# Python Assumes Variable is Local

Tags: python, ipython, global, local

First I will say that this is an assignment and the behavior required is not under my control. I am creating a script called globaltest.py that should act exactly the same if the file is run or if the function within the file is called. I am doing both from ipython. It should create a dictionary called station_dict that can be accessed in the ipython console or seen with the `whos` command.

```
from globaltest import file_to_dict
file_to_dict()
```

This should make a variable called station_dict when the function is run.

And here is the behavior when the script is simply being run:

```
Run globaltest
```

This should also create a dictionary called station_dict.

The issue is calling and using the function file_to_dict does not create the variable while just running the file does. Here is my code. Thanks for any help.

```
#!//bin/env python3

def main():

    global station_dict

    station_dict = {}

    station_dict['foo'] = 'bar'

def file_to_dict():

    global station_dict

    station_dict = {}

    station_dict['foo'] = 'bar'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the bad output as a result of using the function:

```
Python 3.4.5 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:47:47)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: from globaltest import file_to_dict

In [2]: file_to_dict()

In [3]: whos
Variable       Type        Data/Info
------------------------------------
file_to_dict   function    <function file_to_dict at 0x7f869f39cea0>
```

Here is the good output as a result of running the program:

```
Python 3.4.5 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:47:47)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: run globaltest.py

In [2]: whos
Variable       Type        Data/Info
------------------------------------
file_to_dict   function    <function file_to_dict at 0x7fb92b7df8c8>
main           function    <function main at 0x7fb92b7df0d0>
station_dict   dict        n=1
```

Comment: The function `file_to_dict` **does** modify/create the global variable, `station_dict`. You need to provide some sort of [mcve] that shows that it doesn't.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean when you try to describe your "behavior" like `Run a9_[USERNAME]`. You need to be *precise* about what you are doing.

Comment: You do not have any  dictionary by the name `station_dict` in the global scope to begin with!

Comment: By the way, why do u import per function. Importing is supposedly outside, it will be faster.

Comment: I have remade the question as per @juanpa.arrivillaga recommendation. I got rid of all the extra and included an output you can see. Thanks for linking the minimal reproducible example document. I will try to make sure any future questions meet those standards.

Comment: This is just not going to work the way you expect it to. Python has *module-level globals*, not "true" globals. Your function is indeed creating a global variable. `run` is Ipython magic, not sure why you even care about using it. In any case, the global variable you create in your function is *available as `globaltest.station_dict`* if you import it like `import globaltest`

Comment: So is there no way to get the kind of behaviour I am trying to? I care about using run and other specifics because this is how the assignment will be graded. The teacher will put in the commands I indicated into ipython and look for the variable to have been created the the 'whos' command.

Comment: @JohnGarrettWilliamson quite frankly, that's crazy. You *can* do the **very very** hackey way of modifying `__builtins__` (which is the namespace that contains all built-in names like, `list`, `sum` etc) but there's no way the teacher is expecting you to do that, and you **shouldn't** do that.

Comment: So, you know for a fact that the way this is graded is that the teacher just opens up an IPython shell, does `from globaltest import file_to_dict` then runs `file_to_dict` and checks to see if a global variable exists in the `__main__` namespace? Because that just sounds like they dont understand what all of this is doing.

Comment: juanpa is right. I'm thinking you might be missing some detail of the assignment.

Comment: Note, `run` is not even really running something as a module, I'm pretty sure it just extracts the source-code and `exec`'s it in the main namespace. These sorts of things exist for doing the sorts of shenanigans and prototyping you need to do in a shell environment, but they aren't meant to be used in production environments.

Comment: I just confirmed that the assignment was in error. Those were my instructions, but the teacher meant to have a variable equal to the function and they are fixing it.

I mostly wanted to check and make sure I wasn't missing something. I also wanted to understand why the outputs were different when my understanding said they should both work. I appreciate all your help and understand better now why it didn't work how I thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things going on here:

1. What Python calls "global" is not really global, it's module-level (i.e. in the module namespace). So when you run `file_to_dict`, `station_dict` becomes set in `globaltest`'s namespace, though that namespace is not bound (i.e. not imported), so `station_dict` is inaccessible. To access it, you could do:

   ```
   import globaltest
   globaltest.station_dict
   ```
2. IPython's [`%run`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run) runs the code in the interpreter's namespace.

That said, I don't know how to achieve what you want. As far as I know, a function can't set variables in its calling namespace, although it might be possible by getting into hacky stuff like `inspect`.

If it helps, you could read about [sharing variables between modules](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules).

Comment: You can get "global globals" by using the `__builtins__` namespace, although, that is super hacky. In CPython, modying the namespace of the caller, in general, is not really feasible. You *could* probably get to the caller using `inspect`, but then, there's no easy way to modify local namespaces without some serious hackery, I've never seen it done but I won't say it's impossible.